# Display timezone related to user location (Laravel)

Tags: laravel

I use laravel 6, and it's `'timezone' => 'UTC'`. we have thousands users from across the world. ex. Japan, US, China, India, Turkish and ..., In this case we should display post timezone related to the country timezone.

Comment: https://laraveldaily.com/demo-project-managing-timezones-for-every-user-in-laravel/

Answer (score 1):

In order to use users timezone, first that timezone needs to be stored somewhere

for example in DB table `users` under column `timezone`

and then if you need the current time in users timezone you just call this method:

```
$usersCurrentTime = now($user->timezone)->format('Y-m-d H:i:s');
```

That will give you the current time in users timezone.

Answer (score -1):

```
 $date= \Carbon\Carbon::setLocale('en');
```